# Is the point giving the width in strictly convex surface a cut point?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume that $\Sigma$ is a stricly convex surface in $\mathbb{E}^3$ homeomorphic to a sphere. Further, assume that $p_0,\ p_1\in \Sigma$ are intersection points with planes $z=0,\ z=1$ and the surface $\Sigma$ is between the two planes. Then $p_1$ is a cut point of $p_0$ ? (I do not know whether or not this is true)

Definition : Consider a intrinsic metric on $\Sigma$, a length of simple path.
Then $p_1$ is not a cut point of $p_0$ if there is unique shortest
path from $p_0$ to any point sufficiently close to $p_1$.

Comment: Could you please define "cut point"? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the definition.

Comment: Counterexample : Consider a chart $T(u,v)=(0,u,0)+f(u)(\cos\ v,0,\sin\ v),\ f(u)=1-u^4,\ -1\leq u\leq 1,\ v\in [-\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon]$ for the surface. Here $T(0,v)$ is a geodesic and sectional curvature is zero along the geodesic  so that Jacobi field is $t(0,1,0)$ along $T(0,t+\frac{\pi}{2})$

Answer (score 4):

*No*.

It is clear that this is true for a sphere, but cutting of a spherical cap from the sphere leaves the intersection points with the planes the same, but now there is a unique shortest path through this new flat area.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ [image]

Of course you can make this object strictly convex, differentiable etc. by smoothing out the cut.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, it seems that there is no reason that $p_1$ in a tilted
ellipsoid is a cut point of $p_0$.
Because the orientation of the ellipsoid is a global issue
(i.e., the location of $p_0$ and $p_1$ change with the tilt), whereas
cut-point-ness is intrinsic.

---

[image: Ellipsoid]

---

In this symmetric example, perhaps there are a pair of equal-length geodesics
connecting $p_0$ to $p_1$, but if I arranged $\Sigma$ to be asymmetric
with respect to the coordinate axes, there would 
be a unique shortest geodesic connecting those two $z=0,1$ tangency points.